# Asp.net how to get 1 word of a row from an table in a database to another table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

My question is like the title:

how to get 1 word of a row from an table in a database to another table using an username that exists in both tables.

This is what i tried

```
var word = db.QueryValue("SELECT wordlist FROM tableold WHERE username IN(SELECT username FROM tablenew)");
var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO tablenew (wordlist) VALUE(word)";
db.execute(insertCommand, word);
```

With db as my database ofcourse.

The problem here is that" word" can't be inserted here because thats not allowed.

My question: is there a way to do this? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add sample data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the simple awnser was to put @0 at the place of word inside the insert into query

Answer (score 0):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO tablenew (wordlist)
    SELECT wordlist
    FROM tableold 
    WHERE username IN(SELECT username FROM tablenew);
```

Comment: I already did,  just sql commands wont word using c#code in asp.net, thats why i tried what i had above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this approach:

```
DataTable words = new DataTable();
string word = string.Empty;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT wordlist FROM tableold WHERE username IN(SELECT username FROM tablenew)";

     SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adap.SelectCommand = cmd;

     adap.Fill(words);
}

if (words != null && words.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     word = words.Rows[0].Field<string>("wordlist"); // for example
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
          cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tablenew(wordlist) VALUE(@word)";

          conn.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          conn.Close();
      }
}
```